# AngularJS multi-app single sign-on for login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on AngularJS site here i'm trying to implement the single sign on login process in my site by using different applications.

-Once we login into one application it will automatically login to another application and for login i'm using different roles in it.

It was my requirement.Please help me by providing reference demo like for single sign-on.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to read about $route, $routeProvider that will solve your problem.
Read this article it will clear your concept

http://www.jonsamwell.com/url-route-authorization-and-security-in-angular/